# Can I play a card using flashback without it having been successfully cast first?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For instance, if I try to cast [Army of the Damned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Army%20of%20the%20Damned) and my opponent uses [Cancel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cancel) to stop it, can I still cast Army of the Damned from the graveyard for it's Flashback cost?

Comment: Sort of an aside, the phrase "successfully cast" is no longer part of the rules of Magic.  A spell still counts as "cast" if Cancel is used to stop it.

Comment: Cards in the graveyard do not have a "memory" of how they were placed there.  Just the order

Comment: @Andrey, and if playing in a tournament, even order doesn't matter so much (sometimes) 404.2. Each graveyard is kept in a single face-up pile. A player can examine the cards in any graveyard at any time but normally can’t change their order. Additional rules applying to sanctioned tournaments may allow a player to change the order of cards in his or her graveyard.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**. The only requirements for **Flashback** are that the card is in your Graveyard, you are able to pay the alternate Flashback cost, and you are capable of casting the Flashback spell at that particular time (you have priority, if the Flashback spell is a Sorcery then it is you turn's first or second Main Phase and the stack is empty, etc.).

Keep in mind that if your opponent [Cancel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cancel)s your [Army of the Damned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Army%20of%20the%20Damned) spell, that you must wait until Cancel to resolve before your spell will be in the graveyard. If it was [Dissipate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dissipate)d, it would never hit the graveyard at all.

> 702.33a Flashback appears on some instants and sorceries. It represents two static abilities: one that functions while the card is in a player’s graveyard and the other that functions while the card is on the stack. **“Flashback [cost]” means “You may cast this card from your graveyard by paying [cost] rather than paying its mana cost**” and “If the flashback cost was paid, exile this card instead of putting it anywhere else any time it would leave the stack.” Casting a spell using its flashback ability follows the rules for paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2e–g.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Flashback simply lets you cast the spell from your graveyard, it does not matter how the spell got there.